# How may I upload file with formData to node js with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to upload the file on the server with some data, and if I'm right, I need to pass the file and all data in formData, and parse on the server side.

I'm also using Multer for parsing body and save the file on the server, but I don't know how to take my text data from my formData, because Multer takes and read-only file without formData with my data from Form.

How I may take all data in Multer or take form data without Multer?

FrontEnd

```js
let file = file[0];
//some file from input

let data = {
  name: 'Jhon',
  job: 'Engener',
  time: 12
}
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('formData', JSON.stringy(data))

axios.post('someURL', formData);
```

backend

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destanation: (req, file, callback) => {
      callback(null, '/files')
  },
  
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, 'newFile');
  }
});

let upload = multer({storage)};
 
 
api.post('/', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  
});
```

Comment: Honestly, this question is too broad. Multer does have documentation. We can't tell what you've done wrong without a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the code should treat upload and get some posted data in the same operation. A while ago I wrote this snippet of code that works very well, maybe it helps:

```
exports.myPostFunction = function (req, res) {
    var multer = require('multer');

    var path = require('path');
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, process.env.UPLOAD_FOLDER);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, path.extname(file.originalname));
        }
    });

    // Treat posted file
    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).fields([
        { name: 'myImage', maxCount: 1 }, 
    ]);

    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            // ...
        } 

        // Get posted data:
        var obj = { 
            myField1: req.body.myField1,
            myField2: req.body.myField2
        };

        // ...
     });
};
```

In front end:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myField1", data.myField1);
formData.append("myField2", data.myField2);
formData.append("myImage", data.image[0]); // myInputFile.files[0]

$.ajax({
    url: 'someURL',
    type: 'put',
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

Comment: And that function using in router callback with passing req, res as arguments?

Comment: @Drop, yes! Pass `req, res` to `upload` function. I made that because multer first save files and then writes to `req` the remaining data.

Comment: Hi, i did something similar, but it's nowt working. I have router.post('/withimage', alertWithImagePost ); where alertWithImagePost is liket your myPostFunction . It's like it never pass the functions for destination and filename(diskstorage) Did i miss somehing else?